# Exclude weekend days when adding to current date VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, filter

I have the following piece of code, which is excluding all results in excel sheet that have date different than today + 6 days.
The problem is that when I execute that on Monday I hit Sunday. 
I need to change it in a way that it will add always 6 days to my current date unless the result is Saturday or Sunday, then I would like to take the first working day after that, meaning - Monday.

```
    Public Sub GRP_SC_Filter1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    Dim DelDate As Long


    DelDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date) + 6)


    LR = Sheets("Goods Receivable Planning").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<>" & DelDate

    ALR = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ALR > 2 Then
        Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Range("A2:A" & LR).Delete
        Range("A1").Activate
    End If
    Cells.AutoFilter
 '  MsgBox "Finished deleting rows"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I would be really thankful if somebody could help me transforming this into what I need. I am honestly stuck. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you had a look in to the `=NetworkDays()` worksheet function? This will calculate the number of working days between two dates, and may help you achieve what you need.

Comment: You can use the Excel function `WORKDAY` if your weekend is `Sat, Sun`.  If it is other than that, use `WORKDAY.INTL` to define the weekend days.  Both are available in VBA as members of the `WorksheetFunction` object.

Answer (score 3):

This function should do what you want:

```
Function GetNextWorkingDay(dt As Date) As Date
  Select Case Weekday(dt)
    Case 1
      GetNextWorkingDay = DateAdd("d", 1, dt)
    Case 7
      GetNextWorkingDay = DateAdd("d", 2, dt)
    Case Else
      GetNextWorkingDay = dt
  End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `weekDay` can hep you. The second parameter defines what day return 1, `vbMonday` would say that Mondays are 1, Saturday = 6, Sunday = 7

So, one way would be:

```
deldate = DateSerial(Year(Date + 3), Month(Date + 3), Day(Date + 3) + 6)
Do While (Weekday(deldate, vbMonday) >= 6)
    deldate = deldate + 1
Loop
```