# VBA macro button that adds +1 day to a date, but skips weekends?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button that adds +1 day to a date value, but I'd love a way to automate it to skip Saturdays and Sundays.

This is code I'm currently using to add +1 day...

```
Sub Add_1_Day()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngSel As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Num As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lAreas As Long
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lCols As Long
Dim Arr() As Variant
Set rngSel = Selection

Num = 1

For Each rng In rngSel.Areas
  If rng.Count = 1 Then
     rng = rng + Num
  Else
      lRows = rng.Rows.Count
      lCols = rng.Columns.Count
      Arr = rng
      For i = 1 To lRows
         For j = 1 To lCols
            Arr(i, j) = Arr(i, j) + Num
         Next j
      Next i
      rng.Value = Arr
  End If
Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307140/exclude-weekend-days-when-adding-to-current-date-vba

Comment: Also - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekday-function

Answer (score 0):

### Add Workdays to Selection

**One Day (Example)**

```vb
Sub Add_1_Day()
    AddWorkDaysToSelection ' one day; weekend: Sat & Sun; no holidays
End Sub
```

**The Method (Help)**

```vb
' 0000011 (MTWTFSS) means 'Sat' and 'Sun'
Sub AddWorkDaysToSelection( _
        Optional ByVal Days As Long = 1, _
        Optional ByVal Weekend As Variant = "0000011", _
        Optional ByVal Holidays As Variant)
    
    If Selection Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No selection!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
        MsgBox "No range selected!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim NoHolidays As Boolean: NoHolidays = IsMissing(Holidays)
    
    Dim arg As Range, Data() As Variant, cValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    For Each arg In Selection.Areas
        rCount = arg.Rows.Count
        cCount = arg.Columns.Count
        If rCount * cCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = arg.Value
        Else
            Data = arg.Value
        End If
        For r = 1 To rCount
            For c = 1 To cCount
                cValue = Data(r, c)
                If IsDate(cValue) Then
                    If NoHolidays Then
                        Data(r, c) = Application _
                            .WorkDay_Intl(cValue, Days, Weekend)
                    Else
                        Data(r, c) = Application _
                            .WorkDay_Intl(cValue, Days, Weekend, Holidays)
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
        arg.Value = Data
    Next arg

End Sub
```